# Why does OpenSSL show 253 bits?

Tags: elliptic-curves, openssl, key-size, x25519

When using ECDHE with Curve25519, OpenSSL shows:

> Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits

I thought that, when we use X25519, it uses a 256 bit key. Why does OpenSSL say the server temporary key is 253 bits?

Comment: The snarky answer is "253 is what is coded" [in crypto/ec/ecx_meth.c, moved to include/crypto/ecx.h in 3.0](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/756b198d247d0040b7e2abed9b9b12bc6634a3ad). But that cites (only) draft-ietf-curdle-pkix-02 now rfc8410 which is about ASN.1 and doesn't say anything about bit sizes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The order of the base point of Curve25519 is the a 253-bit integer $2^{252}+ 27742317777372353535851937790883648493$. Choosing as private key a random positive integer less than said order is a common choice in cryptosystems based on the difficulty of the Discrete Logarithm in some group. That might be why private keys are said to be 253-bit.

However, per [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/137295): the set of Curve25519 secret keys is defined as those 32-byte bytestrings which, when converted to integer (per [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) convention on top of the byte level), form a 255-bit integer $n\in2^{254}+8\{0,1,2,3,\dots,2^{251}-1\}$. That bytestring is 256 bits, among which 251 are variable, and 5 are set to predefined values (the 3 low-order bits and 2 high-order bits: these are zero, except the second-highest order bit). Nothing reasonably adds up to 253.

Note: that's not to be confused with the security level, believed to be comparable to 128-bit symmetric cryptography (best attack cost $2^{140}$ bit operations).

References:

- Daniel J. Bernstein, [*Curve25519: new Diffie-Hellman speed record*](https://cr.yp.to/ecdh/curve25519-20060209.pdf#page=8), in [proceedings of PKC 2006](https://doi.org/10.1007/11745853_14)
- Daniel J. Bernstein, Niels Duif, Tanja Lange, Peter Schwabe, Bo-Yin Yang: [*High-speed high-security signatures*](https://ed25519.cr.yp.to/ed25519-20110926.pdf#page=8), in [proceedings of CHES 2011](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-23951-9_9) and [JoCE 2012](https://doi.org/10.1007/s13389-012-0027-1).

Comment: The definition of secret keys in the Curve25519 paper defines them to be of 255 bits ($n \in 2^{254} + 8\{0,1,2,3,\dots,2^{251}-1\}$). Does openssl just use the standard definitions of private key (integer mod generator's order)  or what?